# Como filtrar uma pesquisa utilizando SearchView?

Tags: java, android, xml

Estou montando um aplicativo onde em determinada activity uma listagem de usuários cadastrados aparecerá em uma `ListView`. Esta activity também possui uma `SearchView` que serve para filtrar os dados da `ListView` de acordo com o texto escrito. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer esse filtro de informações.

Código xml da SearchView:

```java
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/sv_card_aux"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white_smoke"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/sv_aux"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Código da Activity

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_contas_auxiliares);
  listaContasAux = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaAuxContas);
  svContasAux = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sv_aux);
  svCardContasAux = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.sv_card_aux);

  svCardContasAux.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                svContasAux.setIconified(false);
            }
        });
}
```

Activity com a `SearchView`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Já tentei utilizar um método para filtrar a busca no adapter, mas não consegui, ag

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado aos que viram o post, porém eu e um amigo já encontramos uma solução que consiste em colocar as informações que estão armazenadas no `ListView` em um `ArrayList`, vou mostrar o código:

```java
//Cria a variável usuariosArray na classe Adapter
private ArrayList<Usuarios> usuariosArray;
```

Instância do Adapter:

```java
public AuxliaresAdapter(Context ctx, List<Usuarios> lista) {
        this.contexto = ctx;
        this.listaUsuarios = lista;
        this.usuariosArray = new ArrayList<Usuarios>();
        this.usuariosArray.addAll(lista);
    }
```

Método de filtro de pesquisa no Adapter:

```java
public void myFilter(String name){
        name = name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        listaUsuarios.clear();
        if(name.length() == 0){
            listaUsuarios.addAll(usuariosArray);
        }else{
            for (Usuarios usuarios :  usuariosArray){
                if(usuarios.getEmail().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(name)){
                    listaUsuarios.add(usuarios);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Código da `activity` que contém o `ListView` e o `SearchView`:

```java
svContasAux.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                auxliaresAdapter.myFilter(s.toLowerCase());
                return false;
            }
        });
```